# MySQL best way to store data

Tags: mysql

Currently doing a school project.
I currently have a simple database that stores transaction information.

there is one table named "transactions" with columns:
id (key, auto inc.)
itemID (int, about 500 unique id's)
value (int, value of transaction)
dateTime (dateTime, in which entry was added)

At the moment, it is all dumped into one table, would it be better to have a table for every itemID, and store all the transactions for that particular itemID? Or is that not good practice.

Comment: It's the opposite of good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of scalability you are doing it right. Consider a new item enters in play, you'll have to create a new table for it. Instead the way you are working now you just have to insert new item in items table and insert transaction associated to that item in transactions table calling it with the foreign key.